# Turn some alphabet to specific number in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

i want to make program that will turn your input text into another version.

For example like this:

If I input = "I want some coffee" , it will turn to = " 1 W4NT S0M3 C0FF33".

From this example we get that =

A will turn to 4, O will turn to 0, E will turn to 3, and I will turn to 1.

So, what code to make this program?  i'm sorry i'm so noob in java.
Thank you.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: nothing, i have C code to do that, but i don't know how to make it in JAVA

Comment: @Kyoya then learn Java. this is about the simplest of the simple.

Comment: yeah i know that, but can you give me some hint, how to turn A to 4, E to 3, etc. from my input text ?

Comment: replaceAll could help

Comment: ok, now i have problem. this code : " String result = kal.replace('A', '4'); " will replace only one alphabet, so how i can replace multiple alphabet in same variable ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods. Convert the String to uppercase(if needed). Then run a loop to iterate through the characters of the string. If the character is A,E,I,O, then add 4,3,1,0 to the string s2 else add the current character. (s1="I want some coffee").

```
String s1="I want some coffee";
   s1=s1.toUpperCase();
   String s2="";
   for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++){
       char ch=s1.charAt(i);
       if(ch=='A'||ch=='a')
       s2+="4";
       else if(ch=='O'||ch=='o')
       s2+="0";
       else if(ch=='E'||ch=='e')
       s2+="3";;
       else if(ch=='I'||ch=='i')
       s2+="1";
       else
       s2+=ch;
  }
 System.out.println(s2);
```

Or, you can use replaceAll() method to replace all the occurences of A,E,I,O with 4,3,1,0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String s1="I want some coffee";
   s1=s1.toUpperCase();
   s1=s1.replaceAll("A","4");
   s1=s1.replaceAll("E","3");
   s1=s1.replaceAll("I","1");
   s1=s1.replaceAll("O","0");
   System.out.println(s1);
  }
}
```